# Better way to plot live data with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: canvas, graph, websocket, django-channels, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to plot human vital signs with an vital signs module connected by UART using Raspberry Pi 4 4GB with Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye, Django, channels websocket and chromium + canvas JavaScript but the signals are too slow cause i'm sending 1600 data per second.

Do you know a better way to plot it?

**asgi.py**

```
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from monitor.routing import websocket_urlpatters

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
})
```

**consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from json import dumps
class MonitorConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        while True:
            data = serial.read()#Serial data uart read
            self.send(dumps({'value':data})

    def disconnect(self):
        self.disconnect()
```

**routing.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from monitor.consumers import MonitorConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/socket/', MonitorConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="ecg-wave" width="565"  height="70"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const ecgIWave = document.getElementById('ecg-wave');
const ecgICtx = ecgIWave.getContext('2d');
const graphWidth = ecgIWave.width;
const graphHeight = ecgIWave.height;
let ecgIX = 0, ecgIpX = 0, ecgIY = graphHeight, ecgIpY = graphHeight;
ecgICtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, graphHeight);
const scanBarWidth = 10;
const step = 0.75;
const ecg_step = 0.25;
let ecgIData = 0;
function drawEcgI() {
    ecgIX += ecg_step;
    ecgICtx.clearRect(ecgIX, 0, scanBarWidth, graphHeight);
    ecgICtx.beginPath();
    ecgICtx.moveTo(ecgIpX, ecgIpY);
    ecgICtx.lineJoin= 'round';
    ecgIY = ecgIData/(4096/(graphHeight/2));
    ecgICtx.lineTo(ecgIX, ecgIY);
    ecgICtx.stroke();
    ecgIpX = ecgIX;
    ecgIpY = ecgIY;
    if (ecgIpX > graphWidth) {
        ecgIX = ecgIpX = -ecg_step;
    }
}

const URL = `ws://${window.location.host}/ws/socket/`;
function startButton() {
    let socket = new WebSocket(URL);
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
        let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        ecgIData = data.value;
        requestAnimationFrame(drawEcgI);
    }

}
```

With Raspberry PI OS (2022-09-26), Python 3.9.2 and Django Channels with Daphne 4.0.0

Comment: do you need to save, and process data at the backend or directly send it to other connected frontend devices?

Comment: No, just show the graphs and data in a screen

Comment: peer to peer will work for you? This may save data travel time to backend.